# Why is my FAB refresh button not refreshing on tap in WebView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Hi I have a problem with my WebView flutter app, I have a floating action button but its not refreshing on tap

my code where the fab is located are:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  WebViewController _myController;
      final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                  body: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'https://syncshop.online/en/',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                  _myController = controller;
                },
          onPageFinished: (initialUrl) {
              _myController.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';");
          },
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _myController?.reload();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          ),
          ),
      );
    }
}
```

The FAB is there but not refreshing the webview url when pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two Web View Controller instances.

1. `WebViewController _myController`
2. `Completer<WebViewController> _controller`

What is happening is _myController has been assigned a value, but it doesn't have any data yet.

I would suggest using the `_controller` instance with code as below:

```dart
onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
  _controller.complete(controller);
}
```

and FAB button as:

```dart
    floatingActionButton: FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
          if (controller.hasData) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              controller.data.reload();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          );
          }
          return Container();
        }),
```

The above use of `Completer` allows you to Show a FAB only after the `_contoller` has some data to reload.

Refer to this example code for more details: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/webview_flutter/example/lib/main.dart

Comment: modified this line
```
onPressed: () {
              controller.reload();
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          );
```

to 

```
onPressed: () async {
controller.data.reload();
},
child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
);
}
```
becuase the one you provided for FAB doesnt work with the .data before the reload method

the button shows but upon pressing, nothing happens, it doesnt refresh or shows a rebuilding state of the webview

Comment: The change you made is correct and it should be working as expected after that. I'll let you know ASAP when I figure out the problem.

Comment: yep I know, but is it suppose to do that? no show or indication that it refreshed like when you refresh in a browser? Im new to flutter btw

Comment: btw I got another problem, I think what you have given me is OK now but for some reason the code I injected here ```          onPageFinished: (initialUrl) {
              _myController.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';");
          },```

for some reason it wont work